# How to abseil without a descender device?

Tags: gear, climbing, mountaineering, ropes

Lets assume I am abseiling multiple pitches with some tuber device and at some point at a belay I dropped the device. How do I improvise something that does the braking while descending? I still have standard climbing equipment like biners/slings just no braking device. The less equipment needed the better.

One obvious way is to use a Munter hitch, but as [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/11075/how-to-get-kinks-and-twists-out-of-a-climbing-rope) shows this results in serious twisting of the rope. So I am mostly interested in alternatives and if still is to be the Munter hitch, is there a convenient way to get both strands (loaded towards the top and unloaded towards the bottom) to be parallel?